# Is it possible to have multiple exclude filters for FindBugs?

Tags: filter, findbugs

We have two filter files, one acting as a global filter, and another for project-specific filter files. I would like to make ant know the filter files, but apparently there can be only one excludeFilter. I've tried searching online but all the examples use one filter files. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

FindBugs can handle multiple exclude filters, but it looks like the FindBugs ant task cannot.  From the command line you can use multiple -exclude options.  In the eclipse plugin you can list multiple exclude files.